# Send ArrayList<Product> from Servlet and receive in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

This is my servlet code. Here, `products` is an object of `ArrayList<Products>` and I am sending this to a JSP file. `request` is an object of type `HttpServletRequest`.

```
request.setAttribute("listOfProducts", products);
request.getRequestDispatcher("UpdateProduct.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In my JSP, I tried to receive this.

```
ArrayList<Products> product = request.getAttribute("listOfProducts");
```

It shows me this error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ArrayList

Then I tried this

```
ArrayList<Products> product = (ArrayList<Products>) request.getAttribute("listOfProducts");
```

Then I got this warning

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to 
>        ArrayList
>       - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to 
>        ArrayList

Comment: What kind of object is request?

Comment: Try to instantiate `product` first : `ArrayList<Products> product = new ArrayList<Product>();` and then get it from your `request` with the cast : `product = (ArrayList<Product>) request.getAttribute("listOfProducts");`

Comment: @Asew It doesn't make any sense. You suggest to create object  ant then throw it away. It won't fix problem with casting.

Comment: @user1766169 HttpServletRequest object is request

Comment: Please show you JSP code following the `ArrayList<Products> product = (ArrayList<Products>) request.getAttribute("listOfProducts")` declaration. Java scriptlets in JSPs have not been considered good practice for more than 10 years. There's better ways to do this using JSTL.

Comment: @SteveC  I wrote this top of the page ... <%@page import="root.Model.Products"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

Then i used this.. ArrayList<Products> product = (ArrayList<Products>) request.getAttribute("listOfProducts")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the modern (environmentally friendly!) way to do this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <c:forEach items="${listOfProducts}" var="product">
        <tr><td>${product.id} </td>
            <td>${product.name} </td>
            <td>${product.whatever} </td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The file extension of your JSP must be `.jspx`.

No java code is required in the page.

Comment: My requirement is with scriplet. But the main problem is that i cannot parse that object

Comment: In that case you must provide the details of your runtime environment including the server vendor/version and java version.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7.0.56 and jdk1.8.0_131